# CustomVariableListener with sources of different entities - Parameterization of Listener

Tags: optaplanner

Recently, a question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38141670/optaplanner-shadow-variable-with-more-than-one-source) how to implement a listener where the source variables are on *different* planning entity classes, e.g.

```
@PlanningEntity
class FirstPlanningEntityClass{

  @PlanningVariable
  int a;
}
```

and

```
@PlanningEntity
class SecondPlanningEntityClass{

  @PlanningVariable
  int b;
}
```

In my third (shadow) planning entity I want to update my shadow planning variable when either `a` or `b` changes (i.e., `a` and `b` as sources), such as:

```
@PlanningEntity //shadow planning entity
class ShadowEntityClass{
  @CustomShadowVariable(variableListenerClass = MyListener.class,
        sources = {@CustomShadowVariable.Source(entityClass = FirstEntityClass.class, variableName = "a"),
                @CustomShadowVariable.Source(entityClass = SecondEntityClass.class, variableName = "b")})
  public local int getMyShadowVariable(){...}
```

However, `MyListenerClass` must implement a parameterized `VariableListener` with exactly one type parameter, where the type parameter corresponds to the entity class which the source variable is on:

```
public class MyListenerClass implements VariableListener<Entity_>{...}
```

But the source variables are on *two* planning entity classes.

To solve the problem, I tried several things:

- I can't interface `FirstPlanningEntityClass` and `FirstPlanningEntityClass` with e.g. a common `CommonPlanningEntityInferface` as the two entity classes are wildly different. This common interface could have been used as the type parameter for `VariableListener`.
- I also cannot specify two different listener classes in the `@CustomShadowVariable` argument list, such as

  ```
  @CustomShadowVariable(variableListenerClass = MyFirstListener.class,
  sources = {@CustomShadowVariable.Source(entityClass = FirstPlanningEntity.class, variableName = "a")}, 
  variableListenerClass = MySecondListener.class, 
  sources = {@CustomShadowVariable.Source(entityClass = SecondPlanningEntity.class, variableName = "b")})
  ```
- or two annotations on top of one another, e.g.

  ```
  @CustomShadowVariable(variableListenerClass = MyFirstListener.class,
  sources = {@CustomShadowVariable.Source(entityClass = FirstPlanningEntity.class, variableName = "a")})
  @CustomShadowVariable(variableListenerClass = MySecondListener.class,
  sources = {@CustomShadowVariable.Source(entityClass = SEcondPlanningEntity.class, variableName = "b")})
  ```

The manual only refers to many planning variables of the same class or to one planning variable of a different class (section 4.3.6.4., 6.5.0).

So how can I implement a shadow variable which has as source two planning variables from *different* planning entity classes? The answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38141670/optaplanner-shadow-variable-with-more-than-one-source) mostly covered the change of two shadow variables in *one* planning entity class.

Comment: By design we only allow one variable listener implementation per shadow variable (so they can't contradict each other).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a common interface or just plain old `java.lang.Object` as the generic parameter type:

```
public class MyListenerClass implements VariableListener<Object>{...}
```

Your implementation will probably need `instanceof` checks on the source instance and cast to the first or second class accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for bothering everyone - what a stupid question.

All I need to do is to create two *interim* shadow variables on `ShadowEntityClass` listening to `a` and `b`, respectively. Then, I create a listener on `getMyShadowVariable`with these interim shadow variables, which are now in the same planning entity class, as source.

(However, I still think the annotation signature should not permit shadow variables from more than one planning entity class).

Comment: This is verbose and potentially slower. Try `implements VariableListener<Object>` instead :)